# Entity Framework returns wrong object type if inherited

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following situation

I have an entity A

```
[Table("A")]
public class A
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DbContext with a set of entity A

```
public virtual DbSet<A> AEntities { get; set; }
```

Using e.g.

```
AEntities.FirstOrDefault()
```

will as expected return the first Element of **Type A**

Problem: As soon as I create the class B derived from A

```
public class B : A
{
   public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

calling

```
AEntities.FirstOrDefault()
```

will return a type of **class B** which I find very weird, given, I have nowhere configured class B as an entity

Example Printscreen:
[image]
Shareholder = Type A
ShareholderWithVotes = Type B

where ShareholderWithVotes : Shareholder

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing when you make this conclusion "return a type of B"?

Comment: I've added a printscreen

Comment: And in your db you have some sort of representation of an inheritance hierarchy (TPH/TPT/TPC), such that the first shareholder being pulled is a shareholderwithvotes?

Comment: *I have nowhere configured class B as an entity* - I don't know how to reconcile this statement with your earlier code `public class B...` - class B is clearly "a thing" because you have coded it?

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean, I havent added a db set for it nor set anything via DbModelBuilder, its a class yes. But when I create a entity set for Type A why should it just return another type? That's what puzzles me